# Get product information in admin controller using the order id?

Tags: admin, magento-2.0, sales-order

I want to get the product information like **product id, sku** at admin(backend), When action is being performed on any order. How can I achieve this.

**This is code:**

```
<?php

namespace Custom\Confirm\Controller\Adminhtml\Order;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter;
use Custom\Confirm\Model\ResourceModel\Saleslist\CollectionFactory;

/**
 * Class Payseller.
 */
class MassConfirm extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
     /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $_orderRepository;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Service\InvoiceService
     */
    protected $_invoiceService;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\DB\Transaction
     */
    protected $_transaction;

    protected $_order;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Service\InvoiceService $invoiceService,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $orderInfo,
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Transaction $transaction
    ) {
        $this->_orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->_order = $orderInfo;
        $this->_invoiceService = $invoiceService;
        $this->_transaction = $transaction;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Execute action.
     *
     * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect
     *
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException|\Exception
     */
    public function execute()
    {
            /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();

        $wholedata = $this->getRequest()->getPost();

        foreach ($wholedata['selected'] as $orderId){


         $order = $this->_orderRepository->get($orderId);


                $order2=$this->_order->load($orderId);
                $items = $order2->getAllItems();
                echo $orderId;
                //var_dump($items);
                foreach($items as $i){
                 //var_dump($i);
                 // code to retrieve product id 
                }


                  $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                $order_ = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')
                                           ->load($orderId); 

                $order_->setState("processing")->setStatus("processing");

                $order_->save();  

        }   
        $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('The order has been confirm. '));
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('sales/order/index');
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have product id in order details?

Comment: Yes i have it in variable $orderId.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can get order item detail with below code.

```
$order_ = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')
                                       ->load($orderId); 
$orderItems = $order_->getAllItems();
foreach ($orderItems as $item) {
        $proID = $item->getProductId();
        $itemSku = $item->getSku();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer will try it, and get back to you.

Answer (score 2):

If you have product id in Order Data apply this to get product details:

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory
 */
protected $_productFactory;



public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->_productFactory = $productFactory;
    ...
}
```

Get product ID:

```
$order_ = $_objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')
                                   ->load($orderId); 
$orderItems = $order_->getAllItems();
foreach ($orderItems as $item) 
{
    $productIds[] = $item->getProductId();

}
```

Then use :

```
    $collection = $this->_productFactory->create()->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect(
        'name'
    )->addAttributeToSelect(
        'sku'
    )->addAttributeToSelect(
        'price'
    )->addAttributeToFilter(
        'entity_id', array('in' => $productIds)
    );
```

Comment: how you get product id here i don't understand?

Comment: I have updated my answer, Please check how to get product Ids

Comment: why you are loading the product again when `$item` object containing the information of `sku,product_id`? why need extra code

Comment: `$item` has not all information about product if we need more data like `name, description and images` , We have to user product data.